# How to get sold items from eBay

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I need to get completed listings on eBay using eBay API is it possible? My main aim is to get average price by item.

What kind of API I need to use eBay Finding, eBay Trading or something else and what query should I use for that?

Comment: for now i have tried nothing i just reading a lot of documentation about eBay API services, and looking for help )))

Comment: @imbriarius - Come back and ask a specfic question after you have tried something.  At this point your question is way to broad.

Comment: I find the answer for my goals the best way its to use  Research API for eBay

Answer (score 0):

You need [Trading API's getOrders()](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetOrders.html) operation

> GetOrders is the recommended call to use for order (sales) management.
>   Use this call to retrieve all orders in which the authenticated caller
>   is either the buyer or seller. The order types that can be retrieved
>   with this call are discussed below: